# How do I set a click event in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am new to C# (my job is making me convert from JavaScript) and for some reason I cannot find a straightforward example of setting up a button that calls a method.

I am using C# ASP.NET MVC 2 with the ASPX view engine. This is **not ASP.NET Web Forms**.

My Index.aspx looks like:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Blogs
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <h2>Blogs</h2>
    <button ID="btnBlog" onclick="blogging" runat="server">Blog</button>

</asp:Content>
```

and I have tried several ways of doing this; this last one being:

```
public event EventHandler blogging()
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("clicked");

}
```

Edit: 
Ok so doing the button like:
`<asp:Button ID="btnBlog" OnClick="blogging" runat="server" />`

and method:

```
protected void blogging(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("clicked");

}
```

Tells me that blogging is undefined... how do I call `blogging()`?

Comment: Why do you have `Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>"` in your page directive? And where are you placing your C# code if you haven't specified a code behind?

Comment: I am using an MVC template in Visual Studio 2010. It came with the "non-strongly typed" view

Comment: So is this Web Forms or MVC with the ASPX engine? By the way, the world has moved on from using Visual Studio 2010. You should too.

Comment: MVC. And trust me I would love to but the company that employs me doesn't want to change...

Comment: Then you can't use button click handlers like you're attempting. That's a Web Forms thing. In MVC, you have a form, action methods, and routing. I suggest you take the time to watch [some basic videos describing ASP.NET MVC](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Introduction-to-ASP-NET-MVC), where they'll explain these concepts. By the way, almost nobody uses the ASPX view engine with MVC. I don't know what version of MVC you're on, but you should consider moving to Razor if you want people to be able to help you.

Comment: In MVC, you don't directly call server side methods. You can send an HTTP request to the server (via a form submission, AJAX, or just navigating to a web page), which will get routed to an action method where you can run whatever code you want. In general with MVC, you use JavaScript on the client side in response to button clicks, and use AJAX to call into the server when needed, or submit the form.

Comment: This question should be edited. The behavior you are looking for doesn't exists in MVC. This as stated is Web Form behavior. Unless, you posted wrong and you are not working with MVC at all.

Comment: @jpgrassi Why did you suggest an edit to remove the ASP.NET MVC tag, when this question is about MVC?

Comment: Well I think you and I agree that he's asking something that has nothing to do with MVC right? Also, all the code he posted looks like very much as Web Forms. Since he's new to ASP.NET, my best guess he's asking about Web Forms thinking it is MVC, If not he should not accept my edit to add the MVC tag.

Comment: @jpgrassi No, I completely disagree. He is asking about how execute a C# method from a button click in the context of an ASP.NET MVC site with the ASPX view engine. The reason it looks *like* Web Forms is that MVC 2 used the ASPX engine from Web Forms, and also gradorade tried to use a Web Forms user control which won't work in MVC. That doesn't mean the question isn't about MVC, it just means he took the wrong approach. Removing MVC tag is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks @jpgrassi and @mason! Believe it or not, that actually helped me. I'm kind of being forced to just jump straight into all this, and I assumed controllers could behave like angularJS controllers. I will stop and go back to some basics before I post another C# question...

Comment: Controllers in ASP.NET MVC reside on the server side, so there's going to have to be some sort of HTTP Request in order to reach them. In Angular, the controller is just a JavaScript call away. It's a little different mindset. I highly recommend watching the videos that I linked to in my above comment.

Comment: I see your point mason. You are right.

Comment: StackOverflow: the only place on the web where someone in the comments will admit that someone else was right.

Comment: Well I think it is something good, right? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you meaning to call an action method from `View` then you might try to use one of the following examples below. When creating a link to a controller action in `ASP.NET MVC`, using the generic `ActionLink` method is preferable, because it allows for strongly typed links that are refactoring friendly.

**Default: ActionLink:**

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ID })
```

However, what if we want to have an image that links to an action? You might think that you could combine the `ActionLink` and Image and `Button` helpers like this:

**Using Button:**

```
<button onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index", "Users")';
    return false;">Cancel</button>
```

*(with parameters)*

```
<button onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Detail", "Admin",
    new { Model.ProductID })';return false;">Detail</button>
```

*or*

```
<input type="button" title="Delete" value="Delete" 
    onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Delete", "movies", new { id = item.ID })'" />
```

**Using Image:**

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Delete", "movies", new { id = item.ID })" title="Edit">
    <img src="../../Content/Images/Delete.png" />
</a>
```