# Passing integer to actionLink from partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

ActionLink is executing properly but not passing id variable.

This is executed first in my main view

```
<li>@{ Html.RenderAction("ReviewAverage", "Home", Model.TripId); }</li>
```

which executes this:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult ReviewAverage(int? id)
        {
            Trip trip = db.Trips.Find(id);
            List<int> values = trip.Reviews.Select(review => review.Rating).ToList();
            double average = values.Average();

            ViewData["ReviewAverage"] = average;
            return PartialView("_ReviewAverage", id);
        }
```

This is the partial view that above method returns and which doesn't for some reason pass the id = Model even though Model variable is definitely set.

The actionLink below is not passing the id to my controller

```
@model int

<li>@Model</li>
@Html.ActionLink("Reviews (avg: "+ ViewData["ReviewAverage"] +")", "Reviews", "Home", new { id = Model }))
```

Which should lead to with that id

```
        public ActionResult Reviews(int? id)
        {
            Trip trip = db.Trips.Find(id);
            List<Review> reviews = trip.Reviews;

            return View(reviews);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating a link to a controller action in ASP.NET MVC, using the generic ActionLink method is preferable, because it allows for strongly typed links that are refactoring friendly. Try this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Reviews", "Home", new { id = item.Id })
```

For more information you might have a look at [How do I set a click event in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34929860/how-do-i-set-a-click-event-in-c/34934950#34934950). Hope this helps...

Comment: You are right... ActionLink doesn't expect the controller I was setting the route values as controller I feel silly

Answer (score 1):

The third parameter of the `RenderAction` overload is the route values. The method expects a dictionary with key and value. Make sure the key matches your action method parameter.

You can pass an annonymous object with id property (which matches your `ReviewAverage` action method param name.

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("ReviewAverage", "Home", new { id= Model.TripId} ); }
```

Now for your action link, you are using the overload incorrectly, The overload you are using expects the last parameter to be an anonymous object need to build the html attributes(ex : css class/ other html attributes).

You can use the correct overload which takes 5 parameters ( 4th one is route values nd 5th one is htmlAttributes)

```
@Html.ActionLink("Reviews (avg: "+ ViewData["ReviewAverage"] +")", 
                                           "Reviews", "Home", new { id = Model },null))
```

Comment: Thank you for help, you have explained it in detail but Murat was quicker